# How to capture the Xamarin Carousel Page's back button

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin app and on one of the pages within a **Carousel** page I have implemented tooltips, they work fine.  Click to show, click again to hide.

The issue is that if they are currently shown and the User hits the **back arrow** in the Carousel pages header, **they remain shown**.

I know I can handle the hardware back button and the Carousel's OnCurrentPageChanged() event, but **none** of these are called when the back arrow is clicked in the navigation header.

Does anyone know how to capture that arrow being pressed or an alternative method?

Comment: You can use the plugin https://github.com/alexrainman/CarouselView .And handle the logic in your Viewmodel . `Position="{Binding xxx,Mode=TwoWay}"` . When you click teh arrow ,the value of `Position` will change  .   If you can provide the full code or sample ,I can help you better .

Comment: Lucas, thanks for the idea, just finishing up for the day here in Aus.  I will check that option out and post again tomorrow.

Comment: First impressions is that the plugin seems like it would involve an app re-write.  Still investigating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem by overriding the OnDisappearing() method of the Carousel Page.  Here I loop through the child pages and call a function on each to clear the Tooltips where relevant.

Comment: In the end, I made my own tool tips.